# Suitable synonyms for "migrate", "migrated" based upon the supplied context

Tags: synonyms

I recently [asked a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119392/when-questions-get-migrated) on meta.stackoverflow.com (<strike>please see it for the context; I didn't copy it to this question in order to avoid unnecessary duplication</strike> context quoted below<sup>*</sup>), so the damage (repetition) has been done, however I'd still please like to request your learned assistance and opinions on whether or not I could have used another word(s) that would suit the context? **Move** / **moved** was the best I could come up with after way too much internal deliberation.

**Edit**

<sup>*Repetion in the partial quotes *emphasised*:</sup>

> However, the first time a question I answered got *migrated* (to Pro
> Webmasters), I registered ..
>
> .. their question has been *migrated* to and I ..
>
> .. due to their questions being *migrated*. As it stands now, a lot of the answers to *migrated* questions ..
>
> .. new answers on a *migrated* question until they've registered an account on the site their question was *migrated* to either, and the message they're greeted with
> upon *migration* itself is very perfunctory ..
>
> .. a link to where it was *migrated* to,
> I'd like to make a feature-request that there's a little more prodding
> and cajoling for the OP to register an account on the site their
> question was *migrated* to ..

Comment: Please include some context.  Questions should stand alone to prevent link rot.

Comment: @MonicaCellio -- done. I shortened the quoted parts to just the relevant bits for this question.

Comment: I don't understand the point of this question. In the context of questions being moved around on SE, *migrated* is the prefered word. Using anything else is positively undesirable - that's the specific term we've adopted and endorsed, and consistency is a virtue in such matters.

Comment: @FumbleFingers -- the point of the question, for me, was to find likely synonyms and so far, jwpat7 has just about answered my query and I'll be marking that as the answer after a reasonable amount of time to let other people answer has passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Migrate* and *move* probably are the best words for this; *relocate* also is good.  Some people would understand *shift*, as in "That question was shifted from  stackoverflow.com to overlords.stackexchange".

Beyond those four suitable words, some less-than-perfect possibilities include: *re-site, locomote, transport, re-hang, shuffle off, kick upstairs, down-the-hall it*.

Comment: +1. I quite like _relocate_ and I didn't even think of _shift_. Thanks!

Comment: +1 Kicked though not always upstairs. Gotta checkout *down-the-hall*, though. All good points suggested.

Comment: @Kris, Three links that mention much-photocopied poster or saying "Would you mind taking your silly-ass question down the hall?" are [1](http://www.cbsnews.com/8601-505125_162-47541170-1.html?assetTypeId=41&blogId=), [2](http://www.acronymfinder.com/Would-You-Be-Very-Upset-If-I-Asked-You-To-Take-Your-Silly-Ass-Problem-Down-the-Hall%3F-%28WYBVUIIAYTTYSAPDTH%29.html) [4th item], [3](http://www.jstor.org/pss/541076).  The latter shows only the first page of an academic-looking article about "photocopy lore" in the business environment.